# How to properly and safely run tomcat at IntelliJ and Linux

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, intellij-idea, chmod

## The problem

I installed and configured Tomcat on my Linux Mint for use in IntelliJ.

In the configuration process, I gave permissions, for security reasons, to a new user group (named `tomcat`) and to another new user (also named `tomcat`).

I did it because of some tutorials like the one from Digital Ocean that says:

> For security reasons, you should NOT run tomcat using root user. We shall create a non-login user called tomcat (in group tomcat) to run the server.

So, i executed:

- `$ sudo chgrp -R tomcat /opt/tomcat`
- `$ sudo chmod -R g+r conf`
- `$ sudo chmod g+x conf`
- `$ sudo chown -R tomcat webapps/ work/ temp/ logs/`

So my folder looks like this:

[image]

However, when I run Tomcat, I get the following error:

```
org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.beforeStart Exception fixing docBase for context [/edi]
java.io.IOException: Unable to create the directory [/opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.33/webapps/edi]
```

## What i've tried

As the error implies that it is something related to user permissions, I gave permission to everyone in the folder `/opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.33` using:

- `$ sudo chmod -R 777`

## The doubt

I would like to know what I can do to keep the permission settings for security and at the same time run Tomcat via IntelliJ.

Can I force IntelliJ to run with the user `tomcat`? If so, how can I do it?

Comment: The point of user groups is of course that the specific user that is supposed to run the tomcat service is a member of that group. So, are you sure that the user has been added to that new group?

Comment: Yes, i'm sure. I executed `$ groups tomcat` and returned: `tomcat : tomcat`

Comment: This does not seem like a programming related issue, should this not be on Super User?